# What exactly does the flex tag mean?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I was wondering what the flex tag meant in css. Ive used it for some positioning a few days ago but I was wondering what it exactly does.

Ive googled some explanations and camge to sites like W3 and W3schools but not more than that. And everything there was the same.

> Initial its: 1 0 auto

Most of the explanation is undersandable but I cant seem to find out what the "1 0 auto" means. As is now I still think its an boolean 1 = yes / 0 = no but can someone explain what the flex tag actually does?

Ive used it in CSS like this

```
.flextest {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display: flex;               <---
   align-items: center;
   position: relative;
   top: -81px;
}
```

This works for my problem but im not sure what I did here.

This was not a question here. So either this will be hated or this will be a good addition for the community. So I am sorry if this does not belong here. I saw it as an programming question.

Comment: I find https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ to be a very good flexbox guide

Comment: On Stackoverflow, the flex tag refers to Apache Flex, an Actionscript programming framework.  As for CSS flexbox, I'll leave that to the answers :)

Comment: @Brian Ah oke sorry for putting it back :P and thx for explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by understanding the difference between flex containers and items.

`display: flex` creates a *flex container*.

> A flex container is the box generated by an element with a computed
>   display of flex or inline-flex. In-flow children of a flex container
>   are called flex items and are laid out using the flex layout model.
>   <sub>[Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#box-model)</sub>

You can then customize how *flex items* behave within the container by setting various properties or using the `flex` [shorthand property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property) which allows the grow, shrink, and basis values to be set.

> As is now I still think its an boolean 1 = yes / 0 = no

Correct, 1 = yes and 0 = no.

So `flex: 1 0 auto` (the initial value) specifies that the flex item should grow, not shrink, and be sized using the [auto size basis](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-basis-auto).

Comment: So I created a flex container and that is why my stuff in the container got alligned properly? If you have an flex container all the components inside the container become flex items?

Comment: Correct, each child becomes a flex item (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items). However, you often want to change how the flex items behave, and that's when you use the `flex` property on those items.

Comment: So in theory. I just got lucky with the tag becouse I did not use other flex propperties.

Comment: Correct, you created a flex container with minimumal CSS to control the container/items. There are many other properties you can set on the container and items.

Comment: Ah ok thank you very much for the explanation. Ill accept your answer becouse u litterally answered all my little sub questions Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

The initialisation of flex this way `flex: 1 2 10%;` means that you're setting specific values for the flex property.

```
`/* this is equivalent */
    flex: 1 2 10%; 

    /* to this */
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 2;
    flex-basis: 10%;
```

It is just a shorthand way.

Comment: Ah ok so the left tag is the growth, the middle one is the shrink and the right one is the max percentage it can grow or shrink?

Comment: Exactly. You should take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp). W3Schools has a lot of documentation about flexbox.

Comment: ok thank you for the help! Ill read the documentation some more. And ive upvoted you but Tim Medora answered first and a litle more explaining.